# Help in jquery for dynamic div and p

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I am having a problem which i am not able to understand at the moment. I have a script in jsp which creates dynamic `<p>` and `<div>` tags. Each `<p>` tag has class 'parent' and each div class has class 'child'. Now what I want to achieve is, when a user clicks on a particular `<p>` tag then the `<div>` which is just under that `<p>` should appear. But when I click on `<p>` tag now..its opening all the divs..of other `<p>` tags too. Kindly help me with this.
thanks

Thank you guys...I made few changes in the code..and its working fine now.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".child").hide();
$(".parent").bind('click',function(){



$(this).next('.child').toggle("slow");


    });
```

});

Comment: Can you please show us your code so we know what you have so far and what needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In jQuery

```
$('p.parent').click(function(){ $(this).next('.child').show(); });
```

[The `.next()` method](http://api.jquery.com/next/) tells jQuery to select the "immediately following sibling", which in your case would be the div.

Comment: Might want to do next('.child') just do be sure.

Answer (score 0):

when you use a jquery selector to get a p like this:

```
$('p.parent')
```

it will select ALL p tags with class parent. You will have to be more specific on selecting
`$('p.parent, .child:first')` for example will select the first one, check out http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ for all selectors in jquery.

When you want to select the p that is clicked on, you simply use $(this).

```
$('p.parent').bind('click', function() {
$(this).children('div').show(); // look at how you can use $(this) which will link to the p clicked on
});
```

Comment: I didnt give the -1 but I think its due to how :first being used. That would select the :first element with the class parent. The correct way would be $('.child:first') within the parent. OP wants the first div with the class child selected after clicking n the p tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use children selectors in jquery: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

I can't answer without the code but here's my try:

```
$('p').click(function(){
    $(this).find('div').show();
});
```

this works if the code, wrongly, is something like this: `<p><div></div></p>`.

If you have the code `<p></p><div></div>`, use this:

```
$('p').click(function(){
    $(this).next().show();
});
```